# Defuse the Bomb

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

You suddenly wake up in a room. You have no idea where you are, who you are, and why you are here. A look around yourself shows you to be in a room almost entirely made of depleted uranium other than a small horizontal mirror. As you look around, you see a strange object in the middle of the room. As you observe it closer, it looks like a bomb.

However, this bomb is very different. The timer is counting up rather than down. This bomb seems like it would not explode if you waited. However, you do have a time limit. You do have an incentive to defuse the bomb, however. You don't know why, but you have the feeling that if you defuse it, you will be taken out from the room and fed.

The bomb seems to be divided into 4 different subsections. Each subsection is linked to the bomb so if you make a mistake, it will explode on you.

---

### Section 1: Wires

Here, you see 11 different colors of wires. You believe that all of them have to be cut in a certain order for the section to be defused. The colors of the eleven wires are:

> Red, Orange, Blue, Green, Purple, Yellow, Magenta, Brown, Black, Indigo, Violet.

All the wires are in the order listed.

---

### Section 2: Ciphers

You see a small computer screen with an input. You guess that you have to input a certain phrase and this part will become inactive. The code that is given to you is:

> KIAQQJJLYDTXIODQFABASWHUOTORB
>
> ---

### Section 3: A Physical Puzzle

You find a section where you only have the ability to input letters. This sections comes with a little note. The note is as shown:
[image: The Puzzle is extremely weird...]
The puzzle seems to be written by hand. You have the ability to input four different letters.

---

Section 4: A Maze? For this section, you do not need to input something. It seems to be sort of like a unnecessary job to you. But you are not that naive. You know you should probably solve this easily, so here it is.
[image: You sneaky person! Why are you trying to find clues by editing the text?]

---

How do you defuse the bomb and what do you put in each section?

Hints:

> You probably do not need many hints on all of the sections other than the cipher. However, I will give a hint for section 3. The hint is: If you look carefully, 2's and 3's are never directly next to each other.
>  Section 1 is sorted by a very common method.
>  Section 4's answer is L=O.

To all those telling me that the cipher is unnecessary and makes the program boring, I put it there for a reason. I know the cipher is hard because it's a multi-cipher (even if you put in the correct text, you will get more ciphered text you need to uncipher). However, it is NOT random. The cipher includes parts of the answers to each section, showing me that you understand why and how each section is right. Until then, keep kabooming! :)

Comment: I might add a bounty to this one in 2 days.

Comment: Give a little time for these puzzles. They could take a while, who knows?

Comment: @AnthonyPham Yeah, I bet the cipher will take people a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section 1:

> Alphabetical Sort
>  Black, Blue, Brown, Green, Indigo, Magenta, Orange, Purple, Red, Violet, Yellow
>  BBBGIMOPRVY

Section 2:

> KIAQQJJLYDTXIODQFABASWHUOTORB
>  Vigenere with key from 1 (BBBGIMOPRVY) = jhzkixvwhivwhnxitmmjxygtnngfn
>  need to figure out section 3
>  Caesar cipher with L=O (-3):

Section 3:

> 3 1 4 2
>  2 4 1 3
>  4 ? ? 1
>  ? ? 1 3
>  Hints: position, 1s are diagonal, 2 not next to 3, 2 not next to 2
>  Observations: 3s not next to 2s, 4s diagonal
>  Idea: not a clue

Section 4:

> The solution to the maze looks like L=O

Answer (score 3):

Is Section 1 just:

> Alphabetical?
> So:
> Black, Blue, Brown, Green, Indigo, Magenta, Orange, Purple, Red, Violet, Yellow

Comment: Maybe, or maybe not? I cannot give you the answer. But for now, it has not gone kaboom.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer:**

**Section 2: *(attempt)***

> Based on the section 1 answer, I ordered the cipher in alphabetical order
>  `BBDFGGHHIJMMMOOOPQRRSUVWYYYZZ` and removed the letters of the colours and duplicates (B,G,I,M,O,P,R,V,Y) to get `DFHJQSUWZ` which in Caesar cipher goes to `CEGIPRTVY`?!? Just putting it out there for others...

**Section 3:**

> **Attempt 1 (dead):** <s>Are the numbers: 
>
>  3 1 4 2 
>  2 4 1 3  
>  4 **2 3** 1 
>  **2 4** 1 3 
>
>
>  **Reasoning:** 
>  
>  1. The second row and fourth row matches based on the 3rd,4th columns example 
>
>  2. All **rows** have unique numbers 
>
>  3. (*Theory needs work*) **R3C4->R1C4->R1C1->R3C1=>1->2->3->4**; so I applied the same pattern for **R1C2->R3C2->R3C3->R1C3=>1->2->3->4**</s> 
>  **Attempt 2:** Are the numbers: 
>  3 1 4 2 
>  2 4 1 3  
>  4 **3 2** 1 
>  **2 4** 1 3 
>  **Reasoning:**
>  [image: Crude paint pic due to office constraints...]
>  The numbers do not occupy their numbered position (i.e) 1 is not in 1st column, 2 is not in 2nd column and so on...
>  *So am I alive for now or dead?*

Comment: Kaboom! I will help you out. Rather than worrying about rows and columns, try to relate the position of the numbers.

Comment: To clarify my hint to you, take the case of two. In the picture, no 2 is ever directly next to another 2. What are the cases for 1, 3, and 4?

Comment: @Azync Attempt 2 added. Tell me if the bomb isn't off! :D

Comment: The bomb does not explode. You get lucky, however, because your reasoning is wrong. Try again. It's very easily explainable with words.

Comment: Sorry to say, but it is still wrong. I told you to think about the number's relations. 2s are not next to any other 2s. However, the 1s are always within one space of one another diagonally. Think about it.

Comment: Section 2 is completely wrong, there is no reorganization, just a cipher. Also, to solve section 2, you need to solve all other sections first.

Comment: So pretty much kaboom because you input the wrong thing for both parts. *You have to a permutation of letters in, not random numbers*

Comment: you are in a very weird place. It has not gone Kaboom, but not because you were wrong. Because your input key doesn't have letters.

Comment: so are you not oging to attempt this

Answer (score 1):

PARTIAL ANSWER (not even complete just a thought for others)

> Section 2 solves section 1:
> Cipher has letters that correspond to colours of the wires,
> Take out non-matching letters in the cipher,
> Take out duplicate occurances where you need to (cause you can't cut a wire twice)
> Cut the wires in the order you have.
> My only thought here is what happens to the B's and the missing B for black/blue/brown.
> Example:
> IGYOOHHJWBRVGMBODYZYQUFSMRMPZ
> turns into
> IGYOOBRVGMBOYYMRMP
> which turns into
> IGYOBRVMBP
> cut accordingly, indigo, green, yellow, orange, [black/blue/brown], red, violet, magenta, [black/blue/brown], purple

Comment: Based on the question, we need to cut all the colors... So there needs to be 3 B's...

Comment: thats what i figured. out of the box thinking for you anyway

Comment: Actually section 1 is one of the easiest. You used this sorting in school a lot.

Comment: Ah... Well I guess i'm completely off the rails. :)

Comment: It's more about section 1 solving section 2

Comment: Hint: How were students often sorted?

Comment: @L_Church And also, who says that the cipher is singular and a multi-cipher? (cipher with-in another cipher.)

Answer (score 0):

## Partial Answer

### section 1:

> common color scheme based on wavelength:
>  Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet,Purple,Magenta,Brown,Black

### section 4:

> drawing path from start to end.
>  path looks like letter 'E' and it's mirror image gives number '3'

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts so far...

> Section 1 seems all-but-confirmed to be alphabetical
> Section 2 must apparently be solved last?
> Section 3...I've got no idea (but it's looking for letters, not numbers).
> Section 4, if you follow the maze to the open area then go straight up, left, and down (into the final stretch), the remaining empty spaces look maybe like letters (L, O, and J, all of which are in Section 2).

Comment: Okay, I am getting impatient by some of these answers so section 4 is L=O. use that at your discretion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought about section 1, just in case it isn't alphabetical:

Red, Orange, Blue, Green, Purple, Yellow, Magenta, Brown, Black, Indigo, Violet.

And the OP's comment I'm referring to:

***"Actually section 1 is one of the easiest. You used this sorting in school a lot."***

> Maybe it is just the arranged in **shades**? Not the wavelength, like how crayons would be arranged in a crayon box. I was trying to loosely follow this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors_by_shade but I struggled with where to begin and where to end. It only helps with how to group the colours.

Alternatively,

> If it really isn't the alphabets, it might be **word length**. Similar to how children are arranged height wise. Probably thinking too much. So Red, Blue and so on so forth.

The second option I've given is more in line with OPs second comment:

***"Hint: How were students often sorted? "***

This particular hint probably makes my second option better than the common, alphabet one, since even adults are arranged in alphabetical order for any attendance or whatever, but you don't see...

> adults being arranged height wise. Therefore the word length reasoning may make more sense.

New here, so apologies in advance!

Comment: (hint hint nudge nudge the guy who guessed alphabetical, it didn't explode on him)

Answer (score -1):

For section 1:

> Cut the wires in the order that they appear in the rainbow? It seems too simple but then again....

Comment: Alright then I guess thats just too stupid.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! You may want to take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), it will even give you a [badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges). I edited your answer, adding a ["spoiler tag"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help): ">!" to your explanation to hide it from view until you point at it with your mouse. Your answer was probably downvoted because this possibility has already been suggested (i.e. you didn't add anything new to the answering of this puzzle.) Good luck!